# iOS Simulator never receives notifications from CloudKit server

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, cloudkit, cksubscription

***Important note: The question is not about simulating notifications, it's about receiving real notifications from CloudKit server and get working sync.***

Notifications on Simulator never fires, even when app is launched, I just cannot test my app well. Specifically I've subscribed on CKDatabaseSubscription. Anyone knows how to allow notifications on Simulator to get working sync?

I receive notifications only on real device and have working sync, it works perfect there.

```
func subscriptionToNotifications(for container: CKContainer) {
    if subscriptionIsLocallyCached { return }
    
    let application = UIApplication.shared
    let sharedDatabase = container.sharedCloudDatabase
    
    let subscription = CKDatabaseSubscription(subscriptionID: "shared-changes")
    subscription.recordType = "CD_List"
    
    let notificationInfo = CKSubscription.NotificationInfo()
    notificationInfo.shouldSendContentAvailable = true
    notificationInfo.shouldBadge = true
    notificationInfo.alertBody = "Task list was changed"
    notificationInfo.soundName = "default"
    
    subscription.notificationInfo = notificationInfo;
    
    /// Saving subscription to Shared Database
    container.sharedCloudDatabase.save(subscription) { (subscription, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error saving subscription:\n", error.localizedDescription)
        } else if let subscription = subscription {
            print("Successfully saved Subscription:\n", subscription.debugDescription)
        }
    }
    
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .sound, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error registering notifications authorization")
        } else if granted {
            print("Successfully authorized Notifications!")
        }
    }
    
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    
    /// Creating operation which will notify when subscription will be saved
    let operation = CKModifySubscriptionsOperation(subscriptionsToSave: [subscription], subscriptionIDsToDelete: [])
    
    operation.modifySubscriptionsCompletionBlock = { [unowned self] subscriptions, subscriptionIDs, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error registering notifications authorization")
        } else {
            self.subscriptionIsLocallyCached = true
            print("Successfully modified subscriptions")
        }
    }
    
    operation.qualityOfService = .utility
    
    sharedDatabase.add(operation)
}
```

Comment: If you don't show your code, people have to guess.

Comment: What code do you mean? It's just about allowing notifications on Simulator overall. It works on real device, do not work on Simulator. Please vote it back, it's very important for me.

Comment: I didn't take a vote but please read these - StackOverflow if for questions about problems with code: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Magnas Ok, I've added code. Now you know how to enable notifications on Simulator? I have no idea how the subscription code can help.
I don't have problems with code. I have problem with no-firing notifications on Simulator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudKit notifications will not work most of the time on simulator, you should test on real device.